# How to control log file with daily rolling and max file size by log4j?

Tags: log4j, rollingfileappender

I would like to create log file that can be rolled at the beginning of the next day or if it's reached to specified file size and log file must be contained inside date folder.
Format of folder is `YYYYMMDD` (`/20111103/mylogfile.log`)

Is it possible to do this by Log4j without implementing custom class?

Now I am using log4j and log4j-extra, 
I set FileNamePattern attribute as defined in log4j API to rolling my file everyday 
and set max file size to 50 MB.

My `log4j.xml` is:

```xml
<appender name="MYAPPENDER" class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="encoding" value="UTF-8" />
    <param name="append" value="true" />
    <rollingPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <param name="FileNamePattern" value="${catalina.home}/logs/MY-APP/%d{yyyyMMdd}/MY-APP_%d{yyyyMMddHHmmss}.log" />
    </rollingPolicy>
    <triggeringPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
        <param name="maxFileSize" value="50000000" />
    </triggeringPolicy>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH\:mm\:ss}] %-5p [%c.%M(),%4L] - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

Result of above setting is that log file is not rolled at the beginning of next days but if file's size reached to 50 MB, log file will be rolled.

Please help to advise me. m(_ _)m

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 9):

Daily works for me with xml in question only transformed into log4j.properties equivalent to roll over after 100KB (for testing purposes):

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file

# Direct log messages to a file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.RollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.file.RollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=/path/to/logs/%d{yyyyMMdd}/myLog_%d{yyyyMMddHH}.log
log4j.appender.file.TriggeringPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
log4j.appender.file.TriggeringPolicy.maxFileSize=100000
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.file.Append=true
```

This will create a timestamped directory (one directory per day - optional) with logs with the following format (one per hour for testing purposes - change FileNamePattern to suit your needs):

myCompanyLog_20160203**10**30.log

myCompanyLog_20160203**11**30.log

Answer (score 8):

To enable the daily rolling: *class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender"*

And to enable the max file size and the number of backup files

```xml
<param name="MaxFileSize" value="200MB" />  
<param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="4" />
```

But you can not put `MaxFileSize` with `DailyRolling`, so you can use rolling file appender

An example:

```xml
<appender name="MAIN_FA" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="logs/main.log" />
    <param name="datePattern" value="'-'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'" />
    <param name="append" value="false" />
    <param name="Threshold" value="ALL" />
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="200MB" />  
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="4" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %C{6} (%F:%L) - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

Or you can do this http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender

Answer (score 3):

From the RollingFileAppender [documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/companions/extras/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/rolling/RollingFileAppender.html)

> To be of any use, a RollingFileAppender instance must have both a RollingPolicy and a TriggeringPolicy set up.... TimeBasedRollingPolicy acts both as a RollingPolicy and a
>   TriggeringPolicy.

Hence, your SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy gets ignored since TimeBasedRollingPolicy is configured above. The only way to accommodate your requirement will be a custom classes implementation.

Also, If size of a log file really matters, you may consider using [automatic gzip compression](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/companions/extras/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/rolling/TimeBasedRollingPolicy.html) to eliminate SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy and only have your logs roll every day.

Comment: Sadly, both links are now broken.