# log4j - sizebasedtriggeringpolicy with timebasedrollingpolicy

Tags: java, log4j, rollingfileappender

I want to roll the log file after every 200 MB and gzip it or roll after a day and gzip whichever comes first

For it I have done below configuration (sizebasedtriggeringpolicy with timebasedrollingpolicy), but it is working only when size of the file reaches to 200 MB.

Rolling of logs is not working for each day

```html
<appender name="MYAPPENDER" class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="${catalina.home}/logs/MY-APP.log"/>
    <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG"/>
    <param name="Append" value="true"/>
    <rollingPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <param name="ActiveFileName" value="${catalina.home}/logs/MY-APP.log"/>
        <param name="FileNamePattern" value="${catalina.home}/logs/MY-APP_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.gz" />
    </rollingPolicy>
    <triggeringPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
        <param name="maxFileSize" value="209715200" />
    </triggeringPolicy>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH\:mm\:ss}] %-5p [%c.%M(),%4L] - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

can we use both sizebasedtriggeringpolicy and timebasedrollingpolicy?

please suggest on this.

Comment: hi @Rajeev, have you ever found a solution for this?

Comment: This question has been answered. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7994015/how-to-control-log-file-with-daily-rolling-and-max-file-size-by-log4j/46210380#46210380